# Calabash Android custom folder for step definitions

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

I'm running `calabash-android` command in macOS. I would like to specify custom folder for `step_definitions` and support files.

ex:

> calabash-android run path_to_app.apk -x path_to_steps_folder
>   features_folder`
>
> -x path_to_steps_folder - cannot locate this option.

Answer (score 0):

"Calabash-android run" will forward command line options to cucumber.  The cucumber option to require a file is -r.  So this should work for you:

```
calabash-android run path_to_app.apk -r path_to_steps_folder features_folder
```